# Bug? Using a data transform with date/timeunit

Tags: time-series, transform, vega-lite

For a while now I've been using a `flatten` transform to move data from a columnar data frame to a Vega Lite spec, and wonder if it's the source of a recent problem I've encountered with a time series.  The [time series spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/71f87fe574c403ad345936849d284aa5/spx-time-series.json) is in a gist on the vega editor, along with a similar pattern [plotting sin and cos](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/8adf8b22000332415dc00cfeccbe2a0f/spec.json) that uses `flatten` without a problem.

As near as I can tell, the spx time series *should* work with this transform, and it does work if I flatten the data myself. I'm out of ideas; maybe there's something odd with `flatten` and date/times? I've tried every combination of type specification, timeUnit, etc., I can think of but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone spot an error in the spx time series gist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your dates are not getting parsed properly. It may be a bug but you can easily workaround it by using a calculate to convert your date to a proper date.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgLgTghgdgzgMwPYQLYgFwG1QIDZRhgCmMmWIcADgB4AmhxIANCElaSyABYCWA5ty54kAdy4BjEXCYBdAL7NQEqHgkBXAiUzgkAEUYAKBmHWoAdNXqMAlFyhwdMYuPmzWJqJlAA3VeuJHDFArEyZsEABGAE5ogAYAWjjIpIAmLhj4pJS4gGYM2MTkpIAWAqziuIBWcqKcgA5a7KTopuLIuLaUyMiuhMj01ky6-pqhwubIgDY+yIB2Wcbxiu7W5ZHUwaiJ4tT89ebUsoPdse2VhNSZk5TUtfOR3M6bhNzek9Tsts+4reG0pJnf6-JLXB4AuILD5JJbgkFxe7Az4Db79fZw5HHDGjVHTVGpZ7Y1LvIl-HafPb4sFIy5Qomw4G5L4nJm-NqsoE7VnUrlJOmMmHslpClEstEirECyKcipMvFimJCglKkkCzZK9Fqnmy2lKhm8u5Cp5tEppE1JTU7U1xSVWwHmuLaorWxF2jrmnoeskVU3yuG+-lu-U+-qukPKk6mymRy628My52XJ2lXUx40nKrMuGZtkZi1tHNxoo5wMVHPB4vCvPu6uqnaZyJFwE46vJ6r9UuVyIV5vEguXb2VynuNgcMjYXJVXLmXKxWK5erRKYleolErMSfRcxTeJxX5rxuO1JVDdVermOZTPcIy9VKbH09VbdzPeRXIlVJzObv9eT1LmAlX02SE8gGE9J2neo7mieopiqOZNjgqYNxKLcpkyaIqh6OZuzmcCSjmGcEViPCzyqaJcjwlDzyqaCYK-aI7h3DdZ3MRi5yuPC5nqMCWLmFC4gvHcYPiN8phw6I+JnOcKMXZdV1-BdzBia8jhKQ973A1jD2SEp5JKSitMEhdrxXKCeIfXI3m3Yj6inLC70sp4AKvPdolvTSNyucw4kXWIpis7j4mQ3JjwvOd6gYpjIvAsLAOSYCXzeSzNjY+pXwRWDQp4ryt0hWJYPgxC7y8885l3XyqjXRiYhYwTGNfd9P2-NcWMicw7OvdC8gckK7m3Vy8ime8OmiRTpyoqzp2SArRNycTaqm7cMKw+ZcKMnzypguCEKuEqrPamaROSeaJJY-9kmvdykKckoOt3Rt9MM86L3igYCSSyIvMI6IOj3eaRoRX9P2fRqPy-H8vKfF8gI+0CUru6ZrwB4kgdK58OPE+CLI2q4ro8pz2sXV89JXAzJtCi9Z0KPZya0p8quvOzquJSSlu-OdfnfZ7ArYujOOx3irKmNiqlhkDkvwwSejnVacJiqT2NiAXuKFpTxLB5rIeFliRdg2XsPWljzxAvdvyOYkFffdrfuR4bUbGlDp1oiKoqXNn1PMeDr3Nj8jasrcOZp7mKafHdVIPEojy0wjgPFz6pIC0z6nMoXPfw1IBPCpmqtQ1mWK3MaI-UqPPKssrr3eiW0+nZcSaeybPd8ucAso4mQqjqmMu27KvvfQT8u2oq9o79r5oNtarY-TafdCv2p5twC33BlrfzXGdqaXQL25Qu6g-iWmefX8TMa4nGs4QyvEtA42fL8re2+Clinxl2I5f96ybQKt2pit5zNxgvZaUZdKa-FduVJibNKYNROivbW-VRqAMnMApygktr0QgUuP+-5brmBXN3LKqQcpWQZltQqu0kK31nPXMmR9BIu2-pg5iTUfJ-RvDdDOHVhKYUNlPSC8VfaW0mrRU8e9wJVRcrNE6C02ZVVEXgmGCU4ZvHkXXXSDdxH1FPOeD8p9BbHhHHwQQ5BNzbgqmpDSlkrxe3vq3IKjptFCXxhwx8oNYFa1apOO6exOaH2EYjGGy8PFrzQitXhwjpZR3UbQxuNE6KRSYVAwuUT9wl2jhfThl03IEy0ueEye4zJELToJfBl0e5FILqLOcjYqhi1Vi9S8zjHJaXai+apJRamQmIZTUKBUdrFT6jRMh-SR7fSInOUidkKKTTCt+AhAUKm9M2n04elCllTKQb1Jy-42GOg6Mg-alMkb-XtqNRSRNyKbJQVpCag1rrNN1nfFu28n5WTuoNPZPVgEsVrmEyeFN2pXgKkAh5S03rX0ls-ACxFfodLqd0sOUTHoxK0v+S+8cb7ZWUoEpqENPHORgvM3uXkRaNjnAuJcZNgbng1u4vF5y2IpIsaXJy05SmjUId0u6m9ZKUoUlCxme5mZ50WvNGc6UCkpyKU5H6-Msaqycueeom87E737gNO2gNHbqquFIsSZ0A7LKHhQw5NKcVwPxYRJOkrU6KrYmwlGZyUI2wdactG3MnHZJcT+PB98uZ0xQv+AO-kXkOMNZePVp1RWEXgisk1IVWL739UfdqnDY3GoGYGmeZs55CPwu1dSmqHaKWScXSx+FblNLLuvV+PD-mcM6nubqBzR5dzKZyvunsoJxszSwwtJytVr1yLvbOQrc41Q9rHcB7Ff6NxfuYyO6T3xPl6Rm0Z6r0VKOrrfLCkaZFQtre-bBbFFFVwTlZNFm9k0U0rV60FVkvaKMER-MeMLJnkR5pTbta61nvl9USxZlFWF7oNUpDp7TOn1OttmyEub-bTzAYwmdHtprDNWftdehL20LOIbRcZJFalTJ5mePBrrB2uObiGx+YaJEn2VvK8+k4RYwKCfS1RSLSarmI3lJ9cGrbWPEVuO4OcWYxBHCIcQE4sJpQA7hwixNolceEf+BTyKlPiLHmLJt+zeqnnoSk4VE6UJoVsiC6t3KBF8cboRJ4EzCMfopluFcviQ5aRFt7HNFsP7TnHm-cJbmXJVtZTJ7DxLy7KQXWkkBglPzTsgejWlrHV5eQCZrNjoUV3QXIb24keCmWLrLrl8qImRVsxiB1LLIy1mpSwxynDfcQaNLvYVk2tjQ0JpKVps98NYrnnBcooW3kqpIeihTTOF7SNFqdUs9yV8BtjJY7i5LVlBJqLUwGg6NlgUtu2XgpeS34Eizxs1hGCi5vboyxec7n0Uo7OvJ8ltXlpy1cyvV9GBFruYucscoa5HNuD2y+uymm7usqKWs54OG2H0edg15v+ItV2A9-cxrrEK1Z6xVe1x5Ol1ufpXZcuyO2tJ3SVoxBj6OuET3lhTE2vG4eOeUn86nUtKd+frZU2pdmyLTJuctKnH8w6RfLVJOOW7z1AcQxg5DWcPnNt0+G4SxN9Wir6zCmp8K+5isR1V01V2MWQvVTyil+k16raeDa6VuTGVlpZVpLcKdk62pZ+hfnC9Asnfzfaqb7qa33bl98lh1QudEcbtLUzROpJnmedRhNbKyPFrqk8qj9i+qBzV3CrpmvjIE7M6gtxSX4EVwgxrsZTX2H3rQXFrBY3lKoXnHJKlLE7off15rl+5rgm30QYTrZLP5hpeW53e+vKTdZojcdZXKGKuz3pxp0WrfLJ4eVdHlPp4bao4G4v38eHd0T6jbIia6CEnS6Y0nh+q-T8iUh4ZEcUgkAyBMeRMxNul0kbL-csutT88Hc8Xh-r1dF8JoKpDN853xQlXdrN8N3J7MedqIvZ4kf4kk+Y9EFUY4MkpIjcG9+VwsVI9xmUl1tI68R9G8VtxVHdLc2otsrkK93dy9CsRYAcdc+poYq9Z1Yonx-8btYp-wXtyliF+pGD0NBlR1KpRMoF6p9sLUGVG0Ht5d+phpvdtUH0a9MJi9M8fk+c2dmdE9BD41KCjold98Xosk6DcFVNOMoc0VODMUQYr8D5XMxlEsf9gZoZPsDcjha9yUsDPEiFv8pDE9jtTCWl7oaF1MGkr0-F6YvYDNx1QDlCIiHDeZScVZGMxVMIF8WddU9990ki5Uz41YzUB9tZ5pHl9YtCP5acZ955G4XVFCh14DWCPZU06dqi7cqYXModBcX8QFY5rCwcgNrUbQpVGN05A0L5gDYjRVS08CCs7VT00dLIDJtwOMNFnUz9VVXlO45lQtFlO5dDe1PZfM61tDA8Wi801jFt-CfVg1z81V14k1IiR06Myd8jFi0E+jNdWsV81VJxGcIDgiv4pdRsNoAEe9rljCEDEkXpLjO8llu9c8Noj8f5j1cF2VXswtfiYdn0-48kHoLC6EGiRt3Ys0TCP9FiVMc8I8PUoIqjzi-x5F-EAIkSoSvF5EW8xdMVaMViUVtFHFdF6NXjBMAIJixCFBFAQAAASOACQbgYgVALwDAHgIgKgOADAAAejVJ8GIH4CgHMH4F4DAG4HUAACNzBeAkA1TpTZT5TNTtSoAEg8ADTiBNSnwAArOAJAMgVgWUgQbgMATAKJVgUQXgOgQ0zAVyVgeUiAAAax0EdOcC4FIAkCQDoF4BgH4G8BABoEzIQF4GIDwDoCcBcC4DAAAE8OAdASBUAqAUBVASzeBUBiAABVGAA0nQUs4gKANAT0w0sIEAcU0snMvMgsnQO-B-VgMsisxUgAR3UFgDAANMIF4C1P7PkHkCAA)

[image]

```
{
  "transform": [
    {"flatten": ["spxdate", "open", "high", "low", "close"]},
    {"calculate": "toDate(datum.spxdate)", "as": "new"}
  ],
  "data": {
    "values": {
      "spxdate": [
        "1990-01-02",
        "1990-01-03",
        "1990-01-04",
        "1990-01-05",
        "1990-01-08",
        "1990-01-09",
        "1990-01-10",
        "1990-01-11",
        "1990-01-12",
        "1990-01-15",
        "1990-01-16",
        "1990-01-17",
        "1990-01-18",
        "1990-01-19",
        "1990-01-22",
        "1990-01-23",
        "1990-01-24",
        "1990-01-25",
        "1990-01-26",
        "1990-01-29",
        "1990-01-30",
        "1990-01-31",
        "1990-02-01",
        "1990-02-02",
        "1990-02-05",
        "1990-02-06",
        "1990-02-07",
        "1990-02-08",
        "1990-02-09",
        "1990-02-12",
        "1990-02-13",
        "1990-02-14",
        "1990-02-15",
        "1990-02-16",
        "1990-02-20",
        "1990-02-21",
        "1990-02-22",
        "1990-02-23",
        "1990-02-26",
        "1990-02-27",
        "1990-02-28",
        "1990-03-01",
        "1990-03-02",
        "1990-03-05",
        "1990-03-06",
        "1990-03-07",
        "1990-03-08",
        "1990-03-09",
        "1990-03-12",
        "1990-03-13",
        "1990-03-14",
        "1990-03-15",
        "1990-03-16",
        "1990-03-19",
        "1990-03-20",
        "1990-03-21",
        "1990-03-22",
        "1990-03-23",
        "1990-03-26",
        "1990-03-27",
        "1990-03-28",
        "1990-03-29",
        "1990-03-30",
        "1990-04-02",
        "1990-04-03",
        "1990-04-04",
        "1990-04-05",
        "1990-04-06",
        "1990-04-09",
        "1990-04-10",
        "1990-04-11",
        "1990-04-12",
        "1990-04-16",
        "1990-04-17",
        "1990-04-18",
        "1990-04-19",
        "1990-04-20",
        "1990-04-23",
        "1990-04-24",
        "1990-04-25",
        "1990-04-26",
        "1990-04-27",
        "1990-04-30",
        "1990-05-01",
        "1990-05-02",
        "1990-05-03",
        "1990-05-04",
        "1990-05-07",
        "1990-05-08",
        "1990-05-09",
        "1990-05-10",
        "1990-05-11",
        "1990-05-14",
        "1990-05-15",
        "1990-05-16",
        "1990-05-17",
        "1990-05-18",
        "1990-05-21",
        "1990-05-22",
        "1990-05-23"
      ],
      "open": [
        353.3999938964844,
        359.69000244140625,
        358.760009765625,
        355.6700134277344,
        352.20001220703125,
        353.8299865722656,
        349.6199951171875,
        347.30999755859375,
        348.5299987792969,
        339.92999267578125,
        337,
        340.7699890136719,
        337.3999938964844,
        338.19000244140625,
        339.1400146484375,
        330.3800048828125,
        331.6099853515625,
        330.260009765625,
        326.0899963378906,
        325.79998779296875,
        325.20001220703125,
        322.9800109863281,
        329.0799865722656,
        328.7900085449219,
        330.9200134277344,
        331.8500061035156,
        329.6600036621094,
        333.75,
        333.0199890136719,
        333.6199951171875,
        330.0799865722656,
        331.0199890136719,
        332.010009765625,
        334.8900146484375,
        332.7200012207031,
        327.9100036621094,
        327.6700134277344,
        325.70001220703125,
        324.1600036621094,
        328.67999267578125,
        330.260009765625,
        331.8900146484375,
        332.739990234375,
        335.5400085449219,
        333.739990234375,
        337.92999267578125,
        336.95001220703125,
        340.1199951171875,
        337.92999267578125,
        338.6700134277344,
        336,
        336.8699951171875,
        338.07000732421875,
        341.9100036621094,
        343.5299987792969,
        341.57000732421875,
        339.739990234375,
        335.69000244140625,
        337.2200012207031,
        337.6300048828125,
        341.5,
        342,
        340.7900085449219,
        339.94000244140625,
        338.70001220703125,
        343.6400146484375,
        341.0899963378906,
        340.7300109863281,
        340.0799865722656,
        341.3699951171875,
        342.07000732421875,
        341.9200134277344,
        344.3399963378906,
        344.739990234375,
        344.67999267578125,
        340.7200012207031,
        338.0899963378906,
        335.1199951171875,
        331.04998779296875,
        330.3599853515625,
        332.0299987792969,
        332.9200134277344,
        329.1099853515625,
        330.79998779296875,
        332.25,
        334.4800109863281,
        335.5799865722656,
        338.3900146484375,
        340.5299987792969,
        342.010009765625,
        342.8699951171875,
        343.82000732421875,
        352,
        354.75,
        354.2699890136719,
        354,
        354.4700012207031,
        354.6400146484375,
        358,
        358.42999267578125
      ],
      "high": [
        359.69000244140625,
        360.5899963378906,
        358.760009765625,
        355.6700134277344,
        354.239990234375,
        354.1700134277344,
        349.6199951171875,
        350.1400146484375,
        348.5299987792969,
        339.94000244140625,
        340.75,
        342.010009765625,
        338.3800048828125,
        340.4800109863281,
        339.9599914550781,
        332.760009765625,
        331.7099914550781,
        332.3299865722656,
        328.5799865722656,
        327.30999755859375,
        325.7300109863281,
        329.0799865722656,
        329.8599853515625,
        332.1000061035156,
        332.1600036621094,
        331.8599853515625,
        333.760009765625,
        336.0899963378906,
        334.6000061035156,
        333.6199951171875,
        331.6099853515625,
        333.20001220703125,
        335.2099914550781,
        335.6400146484375,
        332.7200012207031,
        328.1700134277344,
        330.9800109863281,
        326.1499938964844,
        328.6700134277344,
        331.94000244140625,
        333.4800109863281,
        334.3999938964844,
        335.5400085449219,
        336.3800048828125,
        337.92999267578125,
        338.8399963378906,
        340.6600036621094,
        340.2699890136719,
        339.0799865722656,
        338.6700134277344,
        337.6300048828125,
        338.9100036621094,
        341.9100036621094,
        343.760009765625,
        344.489990234375,
        342.3399963378906,
        339.7699890136719,
        337.5799865722656,
        339.739990234375,
        341.5,
        342.5799865722656,
        342.07000732421875,
        341.4100036621094,
        339.94000244140625,
        343.760009765625,
        344.1199951171875,
        342.8500061035156,
        341.7300109863281,
        341.8299865722656,
        342.4100036621094,
        343,
        344.7900085449219,
        347.29998779296875,
        345.19000244140625,
        345.3299865722656,
        340.7200012207031,
        338.5199890136719,
        335.1199951171875,
        332.9700012207031,
        332.739990234375,
        333.760009765625,
        333.57000732421875,
        331.30999755859375,
        332.8299865722656,
        334.4800109863281,
        337.0199890136719,
        338.4599914550781,
        341.07000732421875,
        342.0299987792969,
        343.0799865722656,
        344.9800109863281,
        352.30999755859375,
        358.4100036621094,
        355.0899963378906,
        354.67999267578125,
        356.9200134277344,
        354.6400146484375,
        359.07000732421875,
        360.5,
        359.2900085449219
      ],
      "low": [
        351.9800109863281,
        357.8900146484375,
        352.8900146484375,
        351.3500061035156,
        350.5400085449219,
        349.6099853515625,
        344.32000732421875,
        347.30999755859375,
        339.489990234375,
        336.57000732421875,
        333.3699951171875,
        336.260009765625,
        333.9800109863281,
        338.19000244140625,
        330.2799987792969,
        328.6700134277344,
        324.1700134277344,
        325.3299865722656,
        321.44000244140625,
        321.7900085449219,
        319.8299865722656,
        322.9800109863281,
        327.760009765625,
        328.0899963378906,
        330.45001220703125,
        328.20001220703125,
        326.54998779296875,
        332,
        332.4100036621094,
        329.9700012207031,
        327.9200134277344,
        330.6400146484375,
        331.6099853515625,
        332.4200134277344,
        326.260009765625,
        324.4700012207031,
        325.70001220703125,
        322.1000061035156,
        323.9800109863281,
        328.4700012207031,
        330.1600036621094,
        331.0799865722656,
        332.7200012207031,
        333.489990234375,
        333.57000732421875,
        336.3299865722656,
        336.95001220703125,
        336.8399963378906,
        336.1400146484375,
        335.3599853515625,
        334.92999267578125,
        336.8699951171875,
        338.07000732421875,
        339.1199951171875,
        340.8699951171875,
        339.55999755859375,
        333.6199951171875,
        335.69000244140625,
        337.2200012207031,
        337.0299987792969,
        340.6000061035156,
        339.7699890136719,
        338.2099914550781,
        336.3299865722656,
        338.70001220703125,
        340.3999938964844,
        340.6300048828125,
        338.94000244140625,
        339.8800048828125,
        340.6199951171875,
        341.260009765625,
        341.9100036621094,
        344.1000061035156,
        342.05999755859375,
        340.1099853515625,
        337.5899963378906,
        333.4100036621094,
        330.0899963378906,
        329.7099914550781,
        330.3599853515625,
        330.6700134277344,
        328.7099914550781,
        327.760009765625,
        330.79998779296875,
        332.1499938964844,
        334.4700012207031,
        335.1700134277344,
        338.1099853515625,
        340.1700134277344,
        340.8999938964844,
        342.7699890136719,
        343.82000732421875,
        351.95001220703125,
        352.8399963378906,
        351.95001220703125,
        354,
        352.5199890136719,
        353.7799987792969,
        356.0899963378906,
        356.989990234375
      ],
      "close": [
        359.69000244140625,
        358.760009765625,
        355.6700134277344,
        352.20001220703125,
        353.7900085449219,
        349.6199951171875,
        347.30999755859375,
        348.5299987792969,
        339.92999267578125,
        337,
        340.75,
        337.3999938964844,
        338.19000244140625,
        339.1499938964844,
        330.3800048828125,
        331.6099853515625,
        330.260009765625,
        326.0799865722656,
        325.79998779296875,
        325.20001220703125,
        322.9800109863281,
        329.0799865722656,
        328.7900085449219,
        330.9200134277344,
        331.8500061035156,
        329.6600036621094,
        333.75,
        332.9599914550781,
        333.6199951171875,
        330.0799865722656,
        331.0199890136719,
        332.010009765625,
        334.8900146484375,
        332.7200012207031,
        327.989990234375,
        327.6700134277344,
        325.70001220703125,
        324.1499938964844,
        328.6700134277344,
        330.260009765625,
        331.8900146484375,
        332.739990234375,
        335.5400085449219,
        333.739990234375,
        337.92999267578125,
        336.95001220703125,
        340.2699890136719,
        337.92999267578125,
        338.6700134277344,
        336,
        336.8699951171875,
        338.07000732421875,
        341.9100036621094,
        343.5299987792969,
        341.57000732421875,
        339.739990234375,
        335.69000244140625,
        337.2200012207031,
        337.6300048828125,
        341.5,
        342,
        340.7900085449219,
        339.94000244140625,
        338.70001220703125,
        343.6400146484375,
        341.0899963378906,
        340.7300109863281,
        340.0799865722656,
        341.3699951171875,
        342.07000732421875,
        341.9200134277344,
        344.3399963378906,
        344.739990234375,
        344.67999267578125,
        340.7200012207031,
        338.0899963378906,
        335.1199951171875,
        331.04998779296875,
        330.3599853515625,
        332.0299987792969,
        332.9200134277344,
        329.1099853515625,
        330.79998779296875,
        332.25,
        334.4800109863281,
        335.57000732421875,
        338.3900146484375,
        340.5299987792969,
        342.010009765625,
        342.8599853515625,
        343.82000732421875,
        352,
        354.75,
        354.2799987792969,
        354,
        354.4700012207031,
        354.6400146484375,
        358,
        358.42999267578125,
        359.2900085449219
      ]
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "height": 400,
  "width": 600,
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "new", "type": "temporal", "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate"},
    "y": {"field": "close", "type": "quantitative"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It does look like a bug to me, but I didn't want to call it that since I'm not an expert in this area. The calculate workaround can be added, but it's an additional layer of complexity. Let's hope it's not a bug...

Comment: You could try asking at https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues. One of the developers there will know definitively.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it is a functioning work-around. The issue, reported on the Vega-Lite github repo, is still outstanding after a couple of days.